# How to open url with parameters without clicking the link using windows.location?

Tags: javascript

I just wanted some help with jquery, I have the following jscript which opens a link with corresponding parameters obtained (last 7th day date). However, now I want to make use of the windows.location option so that I won`t need to click the link but just open the html and it will redirect me to the link with the corresponding parameters could you please help me re write this query, I am attaching the js file as well with this message thanks for all your help in advance.

```
<p id="demo7">Link 7</p>
<p>
    <a href="#" id="link3">7th Day</a>
</p>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("link3").onclick = function() {
            var parm4 = document.getElementById("demo7").innerHTML;
            window.open("http:///MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb?Server=S4Port=0&evt=2048001&src=mstrWeb.2048001&documentID=3DFCC92847F95D135AC90A94D8904072&currentViewMedia=2&visMode=0&valuePromptAnswers="+parm4,"_blank");
            return false; // cancel the link 
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    {
        var d = new Date(); 
        d.setDate(d.getDate()-7);
        var x7 = document.getElementById("demo7");
        x7.innerHTML=d.toLocaleDateString();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please take the effort to format your code.

Comment: also please respect your users. window.location cannot be opened in new windows or tabs, it force-changes the current page without the user's consent. That said, you're 90% there, just set window.location = ... after making sure the string you pass is a real URL, and you're done.

Comment: Hi, I am not a js programmer could you explain where to place the   window.location = ... after making sure the string you pass is a real URL?? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
    <script>
    var d = new Date();
    var dateCalculating = d.toLocaleDateString(d.setDate(d.getDate()-7));
    window.onload=function() { window.location.href= 'http://url?param4='+dateCalculating }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("link3").onclick = function() {
            var parm4 = document.getElementById("demo7").innerHTML;
            window.location.href = "http:///MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb?Server=S4&Port=0&evt=2048001&src=mstrWeb.2048001&documentID=3DFCC92847F95D135AC90A94D8904072&currentViewMedia=2&visMode=0&valuePromptAnswers="+parm4;
            return false; // cancel the link 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am not a js programmer could you explain where to place the window.location in the above code exactly?